# Latexdiff with nested files

Tags: latexdiff

I have a problem using `latexdiff` (ver. 1.3.1.1).

I have an Old.tex

```
%% Old.tex %%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,%                       
               11pt%                                                     
           %twoside,%                    
               ]{article}                  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}         
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}         
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}             
\usepackage{hyperref}                       

% Page layout
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}\normalsize

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%number equations after the sections
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

%% counter footnote
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\input{InitialFinalMaterial/settings} 

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{plain} %

\begin{center}
{ \textbf{%\vspace{-3cm}\\ 
\fontsize{13.2}{15}\selectfont\mbox{\hspace{-0cm}PROVA  DIFF}}}

          \vspace{.8cm}
          
         {\scshape{Mario Rossi}} 

\vspace{.15cm}

\textit{Dipartimento di Filosofia}\\

     \vspace{.9cm}

      \textbf{Abstract}
 \end{center}

 {\fontsize{10}{12.25}\selectfont\noindent Lorem ipsum}

\end{titlepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%******************************************************************
% Principal material
%******************************************************************

\input{Paragraph/Old1} 

\end{document}
```

and a New.tex

```
%% New.tex %%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,%                       
               11pt%                                                    
           %twoside,%                    
               ]{article}                  
       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}         
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}        
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}             
\usepackage{hyperref}                    

% Page layout
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}\normalsize

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%number equations after the sections
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

%% counter footnote
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\input{InitialFinalMaterial/settings} 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{plain} %

\begin{center}
{ \textbf{%\vspace{-3cm}\\ 
\fontsize{13.2}{15}\selectfont\mbox{\hspace{-0cm}PROVA  DIFF Latex}}}


          \vspace{.8cm}
          
         {\scshape{Mario Bianchi}} 
\vspace{.15cm}

\textit{Dipartimento di Filosofia e Storia}\\

     \vspace{.9cm}

      \textbf{Abstract}
 \end{center}

 {\fontsize{10}{12.25}\selectfont\noindent Lorem dolor}

\end{titlepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%******************************************************************
% Principal material
%******************************************************************
\input{Paragraph/Old1} %% MODIFIED from the corresponding “Old.tex” file

\end{document}
```

Now, if I first go into the new version's folder with the command
`cd /Users/Andrea/Desktop/Latexdiff/EsempioR/New`, then issue `latexdiff`

```
latexdiff  /Users/Andrea/Desktop/Latexdiff/EsempioR/Old/Old.tex
New.tex > diffs.tex
```

and finally compile diffs.tex

```
%%%% diffs.tex %%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,%                       
%DIF LATEXDIFF DIFFERENCE FILE
%DIF DEL /Users/Andrea/Desktop/Latexdiff/EsempioR/Old/Old.tex   Tue Jan 12 15:16:54 2021
%DIF ADD New.tex                                                Tue Jan 12 15:22:59 2021
               11pt%                                   oneside%                    
           %twoside,%                    % fronte-retro
               ]{article}                  
       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 

\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}         

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}         % matematica



\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}             % colori

\usepackage{hyperref}                       % collegamenti ipertestuali
%\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % Per colorare parti di testo


% Page layout
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}\normalsize

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%number equations after the sections
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

%% counter footnote
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}


  
\input{InitialFinalMaterial/settings} 


 
%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddtex}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdeltex}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFmodbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFmodend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF HYPERREF PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFaddtex{#1}}{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFdeltex{#1}}{}} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF LISTINGS PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{listings} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstdefinelanguage{DIFcode}{ %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF DIFCODE_UNDERLINE %DIF PREAMBLE
  moredelim=[il][\color{red}\sout]{\%DIF\ <\ }, %DIF PREAMBLE
  moredelim=[il][\color{blue}\uwave]{\%DIF\ >\ } %DIF PREAMBLE
} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstdefinestyle{DIFverbatimstyle}{ %DIF PREAMBLE
    language=DIFcode, %DIF PREAMBLE
    basicstyle=\ttfamily, %DIF PREAMBLE
    columns=fullflexible, %DIF PREAMBLE
    keepspaces=true %DIF PREAMBLE
} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstnewenvironment{DIFverbatim}{\lstset{style=DIFverbatimstyle}}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstnewenvironment{DIFverbatim*}{\lstset{style=DIFverbatimstyle,showspaces=true}}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{plain} %



\begin{center}
{ \textbf{%\vspace{-3cm}\\ 
\fontsize{13.2}{15}\selectfont\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{\mbox{\hspace{-0cm}PROVA  DIFF}}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{\mbox{\hspace{-0cm}PROVA  DIFF Latex}}\DIFaddend }}


          \vspace{.8cm}

         {\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \scshape{Mario Rossi}%%%
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \scshape{Mario Bianchi}\DIFaddend } 
\vspace{.15cm}

\textit{Dipartimento di Filosofia \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{e Storia}\DIFaddend }\\

     \vspace{.9cm}

      \textbf{Abstract}
 \end{center}

 {\fontsize{10}{12.25}\selectfont\noindent Lorem \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{ipsum}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{dolor}\DIFaddend }

\end{titlepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%DIF < %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%DIF < %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%******************************************************************
%DIF <  Initial Material 
%DIF < ******************************************************************
\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < 

%DIFDELCMD < %%%
%DIF < ******************************************************************
\DIFdelend % Principal material
%******************************************************************
\input{Paragraph/Old1} %DIF > % MODIFICATO rispetto al corrispettivo Old.tex




\end{document}
```

differences are well highlighted but not those contained in the nested file Old1.tex.
I also tried the `flatten` option, i.e.

```
latexdiff ‐‐flatten /Users/Andrea/Desktop/Latexdiff/EsempioR/Old/Old.tex
New.tex > diffs.tex
```

but it returns the following error:

```
2 and only 2 non-option arguments required.  Write latexdiff -h to get help
```

Do you have any solution to include the nested file Old1.tex when highlighting the differences between Old.tex and New.tex?

EDIT after frederik's hint (see comments below)

I renamed `\input{Paragraph/Old1}` in New.tex as `\input{Paragraph/New1}`. Then I issued the following commands:

`cd /Users/Andrea/Desktop/Latexdiff/EsempioR/Old latexdiff --preamble=/dev/null --flatten Old.tex Old.tex > Old-flattened.tex`

`cd /Users/Andrea/Desktop/Latexdiff/EsempioR/New latexdiff --preamble=/dev/null --flatten New.tex New.tex > New-flattened.tex`

`latexdiff -t UNDERLINE /Users/Andrea/Desktop/Latexdiff/EsempioR/Old/Old-flattened.tex New-flattened.tex > diffs-flattened.tex`

The diffs-flattened.pdf file is right, however in compiling diffs-flattened.tex I encountered the following two errors:
`Package Listings Error: Environment DIFverbatim already defined` and
`Package Listings Error: Environment DIFverbatim* already defined`

How can I solve them?

Comment: Sorry I cannot reproduce this. If I execute I get:
WARNING: Could not find included file /home/tilmann/tmp/Paragraph/Old1.tex. I will continue but not expand |\input{Paragraph/Old1}|
and similar for other included files.  If I create a dummy Old1.tex, then the warning disappears for that input as expected.   No clue what's wrong for you.  Try latexdiff --version   if you maybe have a really really old version of latexdiff (prior to implementation of --flatten) being accidentally accessed

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Old1.tex is a nested file and I haven't reported its contents here because I just wanted to highlight the problem I'm having. That is, the fact that changes in a nested file are not detected by latexdiff. 
With latexdiff --version I get 
This is LATEXDIFF 1.3.1.1 (Algorithm::Diff 1.15 so, Perl v5.18.4)
  (c) 2004-2020 F J Tilmann

Comment: This is exactly the problem that --flatten is meant to address. Why this is not working with the command you posted is a mystery to me.  You can also apply latexdiff separately to the imported file, but then you would have to manually change the \input command in the master diff file to access the diff'ed import, which is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: What I also don't get about your example is that 
\input{Paragraph/Old1}
is in both new and old file.  latexdiff --flatten  will generally IIRC use the current directory as root, so your example will not work well in any case (though your problem is different, as it doesn't even process the --flatten option).  Your best bet might be to use external flatten tool first (e.g. flatex) - you can coerce latexdiff to flatten only with "latexdiff --preamble=/dev/null --flatten file.tex file.tex > file-flattened.tex"   (in linux)

Comment: The problem is almost solved as you can see above (see "EDIT after frederik's hint").

Comment: That's odd again. Have you looked at diffs-flattened.tex  and its flattened inputs to where the dual definition of DIFverbatim is occurring?     Really this should only be introduced once in the final preamble.  If it's already in the flattened file  then --preamble=/dev/null is not processed properly.